# ElasticSearch installation error - curl: (7) Failed connect to localhost:9200; Connection refused

Tags: elasticsearch, centos, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm trying to configure ElasticSearch with [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-elasticsearch-on-centos-7) tutorial

I did everything except step 4 of the tutorial.

---

In step 5, when I run this command:

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200'
```

I get this error:

```
curl: (7) Failed connect to localhost:9200; Connection refused
```

---

I have tried two different things to fix the error:

1. network.bind_host: 0.0.0.0
2. network :
   host : 192.168.2.229

But neither solved the problem.

What should I do to test Elasticsearch and solve this error?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you run `sudo service elasticsearch restart`?

Comment: What do you see in `/var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log`? Also what does `ps -edf | grep java` return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to uncomment these lines in your elastic-search configuration file:

```
cluster.name: your_cluster_name 
node.name: "Your Node Name"
network.bind_host: localhost
network.publish_host: 0.0.0.0
network.host: 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: also don't forget to `sudo service elasticsearch restart` and `start` elastic-search again

Answer (score -3):

run this command.

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:9200
```